# Generating address and private key using web3js in ethereum

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

How we generate address and private key using web3js in ethereum?

please someone help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using web3.js 1.0.0, see [`web3.eth.accounts.create`](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#create).

If you're using 0.2x.x, I don't think web3.js includes a way to do this, but you can use [`ethereumjs-wallet`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet).

Answer (score 0):

`web3-eth-accounts` is the standalone package to perform account-related operations, see the following

Code Snippet

```
const Accounts = require('web3-eth-accounts')
const provider = 'wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/<your-infura-project-key>'
const accounts = new Accounts(provider)
const wallet = accounts.create()
console.log(`Private Key: \n${wallet.privateKey}`)
console.log(`Address: \n${wallet.address}`)
```

Output:

```
Private Key:
0xa81aa482c47342fb...

Address:
0x85fB46c47D8...
```